# Airplane mode on by default GNOME

Tags: gnome, default, airplane-mode

Whenever I start up GNOME, airplane mode is on by default regardless of whether I turned it off since shutting down. I've looked through all the forums and have only seen solutions related to rfkill unblocking, even though nothing is blocked as seen below.

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In addition, a the airplane mode toggle indicator shows up on start up to alert me that airplane mode is on, then it automatically shows the toggled off indicator. When I go to settings afterward, airplane mode is still on and wifi is disabled, and I manually have to turn it on.

Any help is greatly appreciated (I'm still very new to Linux)!